# Is "you could've have had this" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, tense

Isn't the extra "have" unnecessary as "could've" already means "could have"?
I think the correct way to say this is either "you could have had this" or "you could've had this".

Comment: "Could've have had" is ungrammatical.  Where did you read this.?  I can find 1 example on the web,  a self-published erotic story on Tumblr (not exactly a high-quality source)

Comment: A friend said it while conversing.

Comment: And was this friend a non-native speaker? Random things heard in conversation without content and uttered by strangers, people who are probably non-native speakers do not make for good questions. Lastly, how can we know that you didn't mishear?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm whether it was correct. I couldn't have misheard because we were texting.

Comment: Pay more attention to what you write. Native speakers are unlikely to guess what you mean I refer to your earlier comment `friend said it while conversing` you didn't say "wrote" or "texted" and this is why I surmised you may have misheard.

Comment: If your friend is an English speaker it could be one  of two things a) a typo b) his dialect. If it is b) please tell us which coubrty and more importantly his or her region.

Comment: It wasn't a typo or their dialect. Besides, my friend being from any particular country or region does not change the grammaticality of "you could've have had this".

Comment: @genmegusta I would not claim that I know of a dialect where this particular phrase is correct, but there might be one somewhere, hence Mari-Lou's question.  There are many examples in the UK, USA and other English speaking countries where local dialects and creoles differ markedly in word usage and grammar from standard English such as RP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You could've have had this" is incorrect grammar.  The extra "have" is not only unnecessary, it is forbidden. It is a plausible mistake for someone to make, especially in writing  (doubled words are a common writing mistake). But it is absolutely no more than a mistake. The fix is, as you suggest, to remove either "have" or "'ve".